# Criando um sistema de "match" com dias da semana e periodos diferentes entre duas tables

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, tabela-html

nquanto fazia um projeto universitário, me deparei com um problema que se mostrou um empecilho. Preciso criar um sistema cujo é necessario que um usuário, selecione dias da semana e períodos(noturno, diurno, matutino) de forma que lhe for conveniente. Ex: o usuário está disponível na segunda de manhã e tarde e no domingo a noite.

Selecionados os dias e períodos disponíveis(via checkboxes no site), esse usuário irá se deparar com "trabalhos e projetos" que estão dentro de seu perfil e dias disponíveis. Visto que os projetos também devem ter essa opção para selecionar seus dias e períodos no momento de sua criação.

O grande problema está na criação dessa parte específica, quebrei a cabeça com algumas tables e sobre formas de cruzar essas informações no banco, mas nada me pareceu que iria funcionar.

[image: Visto que as relações entre as tables ainda está por fazer]

Comment: Uma ideia que funcionaria seria cadastrar tudo na tabela voluntario, porem ficaria enorme e inviável.

Answer (score 0):

Uma prática utilizada é utilizar da sequência binária para operações como estas.
Na tabela voluntario, vc teria uma propriedade para armazenar os dias disponíveis:

- Domingo - 1000000
- Segunda - 0100000
- Terça - 0010000
- Quarta - 0001000
- Quinta - 0000100
- Sexta - 0000010
- Sábado - 0000001

Quando quiser acumular os dias é fazer um *OR* entre os valores.
Quando o voluntário puder **segunda**, **terça** e **sábado**, será gravado 0110001 (ou 49, que é o decimal correspondente)

Para o período faz a mesma lógica:

- Manhã - 100
- Tarde - 010
- Noite - 001

Quando o voluntário puder de manhã e de noite será gravado 101

Comment: Uma fonte que pode utilizar: http://sqlfool.com/2009/02/bitwise-operations/

Comment: Muito obrigado! Porém ainda resta uma dúvida. Cada voluntário contem todos os seus dias da semana, vinculados a um período. Sendo assim como ficaria o relacionamento dessas tabelas, visto que futuramente eu irei fazer um INSERT para cada voluntario, cada dia e em cada dia um periodo diferente.

Comment: Faz uma outra tabela somente com as relações, id voluntário, dias, períodos.